# why ibdata1 file has consumed less space than .frm + .MYD + .MYI files?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I was looking for ibdata1 file size but got wondered by seeing it just 11MB. There is also another folder by name `manu` which is same as database name and it is 15GB. ( on my local machine)

I looked into live server and their it is quite opposite!

ibdata1 file is 128 GB and folder having .frm + .MYD +.MYI files size was less.

If I look for statistics (local machine)-

```
manu DB is 15GB
ibdata1 is 11MB
```

and along with this, in folder 'manu', every table has 3 files - (just for an example: table `NEWS`).

```
NEWS.frm
NEWS.MYD
NEWS.MYI
```

many times I have dropped all the tables from 'manu' (on my local) and recreated table.

My question is- why the live DB has everything in ibdata (I assume ibdata1 will contain all data what we see in mysql tables) and why on live ibdata1 is very less and files related to them are large in size. Is it not storing all the data in ibdata1 on my local?

What may be the issue.

Actually I wanted to rebuild the DB and set innodb_file_per_table since many deleted table have not released the space and DB size is growing bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your local server uses a different engine for tables than your live server.

When tables are of engine InnoDB their data is stored in ibdata1, when they are stored in .MY* files they are of engine MyISAM.

In a database there can be even a mix of tables with different engines.

The main difference is, that InnoDB is capable of transactions. Which means that statements can get reverted when anything fails, while this is not possible with MyISAM.

A default engine for newly created tables can be specified when creating the database. I guess that happened in your case. You can simply dump your tables and in the created backup script you can replace the engine at the end of each `CREATE TABLE` statement. Then insert the data again and you're fine.

Comment: How can I make it same as live server. If I take a backup of live DB and dump it on local will both be same?

Answer (score 0):

I Know that this is a bit old question, but an important thing to add is that ibdata stores the data from InnoDB Tables by 2 ways:

1- Without my.cnf (my.ini) innodb_file_per_table enabled, all the data from InnoDB tables are stored into the ibdata file, if somewhat it corrupts, congratulations, you just lose everything!

2- with my.cnf (my.ini) innodb_file_per_table enabled, each table (.frm) will have its own data file (.ibd) and ibdata1 will be used as "cache"/"working file", if you corrupt your mysql you can recover your data with the .ibd files.

Some ways to recover your tables for dump (after the operations the tables become useless) are as follows:
http://www.chriscalender.com/recovering-an-innodb-table-from-only-an-ibd-file/
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
http://www.quora.com/Jordan-Ryan/Web-Dev/How-to-Recover-innoDB-MySQL-files-using-MAMP-on-a-Mac

If you lose your data, never, EVER use "innodb_force_recovery" before backing up your files, as this will destroy your ibdata files, even with values 1, 2 and 3, there is a risk, with values 4, 5 and 6, its certain to cause damages as they're a more agressive way to force mysql to read the data for dumping. (details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_force_recovery)

Lastly but not less important, to avoid getting a corrupt ibdata file and losing your data, ALWAYS EXPLICITY DECLARE innodb_fast_shutdown=0 in your my.cnf (my.ini) file, as its default value if you don't declare it, is "1", fast shutdown will ignore some security operations and can easily corrupt your ibdata file.
details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown

More InnoDB Parameters:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html